# MPAndroidChart lib with Androidx

Tags: mpandroidchart, androidx

I was working with MPAndroidChart lib on the android project. But as soon as I changed it to ANdroidx, it started giving me an error.

Failed to resolve: com.github.PhilJay:MPAndroidChart:v3.1.0

Can anyone know how I can fix that?

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

I had to add the following code in the gradle file.

```
repositories {
        maven { url "https://jitpack.io" }
    }
```